# Disabling JSONObject auto-escaping strings

Tags: java, android, json

I'm using `org.json.JSONObject` in an Android app and apparently the `toString()` method auto-escapes all sorts of characters that do not need to be escaped (i.e. string "auto/vehicle" is escaped to "auto\/vehicle") and that's causing all sorts problems upstream. Is there a way to override that behavior?

Comment: Unless I misread json.org documentation ``/`` should be escaped to ``\/`` by definition.

Comment: you could extend JSONObject and write your own toString method. but it writes a JSON string escaped as it is supposed to be.

Comment: Interesting. I'm guessing the upstream server is expecting (erroneously perhaps) unescaped strings in the JSON body. Thanks for the info.